# Building a C# / ASP.NET API using oAuth for API Authentication

Tags: c#, api, authentication, oauth, http-authentication

Does anyone have any examples or advice for how to go about using oAuth to provide the authentication mechanism for an API that should be publicly exposed?

Specifically I'm talking about being an oAuth provider for my own API, not integrating or authenticating with anyone else's API.

For example, I wish to be able to issue API keys to developers that they can use to authenticate and access my API, much in the same way Flickr does, and as far as I believe oAuth can support this, but I'm not sure how the solution would be structured?

Comment: Hi jmcd, did you get any further with your api using oauth. Thinking about the same? I woudl not mind create open source project to implement core of api using oAuth. kind as template.

Comment: Unfortuantely, I did not. I was working at a startup at the time and just didn't have the time to spend getting this to work in DotNetOpenAuth so I moved on and rolled my own using something simpler.

Comment: "so I moved on and rolled my own using something simpler" - just curious what that was?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that DotNetOpenAuth has an example by the way of the OAuthSeviceProvider project in the Samples folder included in the distribution. It's written in WinForms and isn't cleanly written but definitely serves as a good starting point.